# Why is XCTest wait for expectation hanging an async background task?

Tags: swift, async-await, xctest, xctestexpectation

I've been experiencing some failures in tests and I've worked out they appear to be caused by XCTest expectation waits suspending the `Task` instances. Even when they're on a background thread.

Here's a made up test that's a vastly simplified version of the code in my app (please excuse the prints, that's just me mucking around trying to see the sequencing):

```swift
    func testTask() async throws {

        let exp = expectation(description: "")
        print("Queuing")
        Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            let duration = try await ContinuousClock().measure {
                print("  Initialing task sleep")
                try await Task.sleep(for:.seconds(1))
            }
            print("  Fulfilling after \(duration)")
            exp.fulfill()
        }

        print("Waiting")
        wait(for: [exp], timeout: 4.0)
        print("Finished")
    }
```

Now when I run this test the task executes on a background thread and suspends as expected, however it stays suspended for at least 4 seconds and doesn't fulfil until after the expectation has timed out.

Everything I've read so far suggests that you should be able to use expectations with Tasks but so far it's not worked for me.

Am I missing something, or will I have to write some await code to act like an expectation instead?

*Notes: This test is a vastly simplified version of a situation in my app. So whilst it may make no sense as a standalone test, it's an accurate representation of what I'm testing. There is also the notion of a traditional completion in it because the real code triggers background tasks which then notify other code of when they finish.*

Comment: The problem is that you are not awaiting your Task. But it's just about always wrong to make a Task inside what is already an async context. Just get rid of your Task. Simply await your continuous clock _directly_.

Comment: Also I hope that's not a completion handler. You can't really use a completion handler inside async/await, they are opposites.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But this is a simulation of a vastly more complex piece of code which does `Task.detach {...}` background threads to do some processing. And yes there are completion handlers involved as the code cannot await the background tasks.

Comment: This is not about tests and expectations and waiting, it's about how asynchronous works. Your test is ending before your inner task even starts.

Comment: The above has problems (I'd either remove `async` keyword because it's not currently `await`ing anything; or change it to `await` and lose the expectation). See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/d8a97eb54eb9c9dc339e0dafe2a3515d. But I am unable to reproduce the problem you describe. For me, the test (even as supplied above) finishes successfully in one second. We need a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: drekka - Please note that if you're testing this on a iOS simulator, the cooperative thread pool is (annoyingly) artificially constrained. If iOS, try testing on a physical device.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Rob, Yes it's running on a sim during a normal test run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can remove the `async` from the test declaration, then this works where `wait(for:)` doesn't:

```swift
waitForExpectations(timeout: 4.0)
```

It's also possible to `await` the expectations in an `async` test:

```swift
await waitForExpectations(timeout: 4.0)
```

I have no explanation for why this works, and `wait(for: [exp], timeout: 4.0)` does not.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Unfortunately I can't remove the async. In the real tests this is based on there are awaits going on. Plus the Task is being setup and executed far away from the test code. Essentially the above is a crude hack designed to produce the same scenario as the real code, which are integration tests verifying a complete API. So they can't use mocks, etc :-( But since yesterday I've written a function that acts like an XCTestWaiter but based around async/await code and it's working perfectly. So I've in a sense solved my problem.

Comment: I just tried using "await waitForExpecations(..." and to my surprise it worked. Why when "wait(for:..." and "await wait(For:..." don't I don't know as I would expect them all to behave the same. But if there's anything I've learned in 12 years of unit testing iOS, it's that there's always another surprise.

Answer (score 5):

Apple has admitted a problem with `wait` function in combination with async/await - as per [Xcode 14.3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes#Testing).

> Fixed: `XCTestCase.wait(for:timeout:enforceOrder:)` and related methods are now marked unavailable in concurrent Swift functions because they can cause a test to deadlock. Instead, you can use the new concurrency-safe `XCTestCase.fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:)` method. (91453026)

So, if you're using Xcode 14.3 (or higher), you should use async version of
[fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter/4109474-fulfillment)