# Why this test case hangs when run on a simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, asynchronous, xctest

Consider this simple test case

```
func test_Example() async {
    let exp = expectation(description: "It's the expectation")
        
    Task {
        print("Task says: Hello!")
        exp.fulfill()
    }
        
    wait(for: [exp], timeout: 600)
}
```

When I run this on an actual device, the test passes. However, when I run it on a simulator, it hangs and never completes.

Removing the `async` keyword from the function declaration solves the issue and the test passes on a simulator as well.

My actual use case / tests require the test to be `async`, so removing it is not really an option.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758267/why-is-xctest-wait-for-expectation-hanging-an-async-background-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Change `wait(for:)` to `await waitForExpectations(timeout:)`

I don't know why it works, but probably it has something to do with the limited amount of threads available in a simulator.

`waitForExpectations(timeout:)` is marked with `@MainActor` and `wait(for:)` is not.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here doesn't really have anything to do with testing; it seems to have to do with what `async/await` *is*.

In your "simple test case", you have mistakenly added `async` to a method that is *not* `async` — that is, it doesn't make any `await` calls to an `async` method. This has nothing to do with tests, really; it's just a wrong thing to do in general, even though the compiler does not help you by warning you about it.

On the contrary, the chief purpose of a Task block is usually to let you call an `async` method in a context that is *not* `async`. That is why, when you take away the `async` designation, everything goes fine; you are behaving a lot more correctly.

However, the example still suffers from the problem that you aren't doing anything `async` even *inside* the Task. A more appropriate use of a Task would look more like this:

```
    func test_Example() {
        let exp = expectation(description: "It's the expectation")

        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            print("Task says: Hello!")
            exp.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [exp], timeout: 4)
    }
```

I have deliberately configured my numbers so that we are actually testing something here. This test passes, but if you change the `4` in the last line to `2`, it fails — thus proving that we really are testing whether the Task finished in the given time, and failing if it doesn't.

If you're going to mark a test as `async`, then you would not use a Task inside it; you are *already* in a Task! But if we do that, then there is no need to wait for any expectations at all; the word `await` *already* waits:

```
    func test_Example() async throws {
        print("Task starts")
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
        print("Task says: Hello!") // three seconds later
    }
```

But at this point we are no longer testing anything. And that's sort of the point; there isn't anything about your original `async` example that is `async`, so it remains unclear why we here in the first place.

Comment: OP: "My actual use case / tests require the test to be `async`, so removing it is not really an option."